# JQuery change width that given in percent issue.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this script for my smile slider http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl,

but when I try to set `#slider ul li width to 90%` in css it want work, I've checked js and if I use percent width intend of pixel it return for me 0 value for

```
var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
```

but if I for example set `#slider ul li width to 100px;` in css it calculate it in right way.

I have read about the percent and pixels different and seems everybody says that `$('#slider ul li').width()` should return px instead of percent, but it return 0 for me.

Just what I want it is make my slider with 90% width and max-width 760 px, but when I change width it causes on the calculation js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `ul` to be `slideCount * slideWidth`. If you're slide is 500px width with 4 slides, the `ul` width will be 2000px. If your `li` width is set to 90%, that's 1800px. You see?

You want to set each `li` width to be the same as the slider width, so add the line in the middle to your code:

```
...
$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
$('#slider ul li').css({ width: slideWidth });
$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
...
```

You determine the slide width by styling the `li`, but when setting up you're slider with jquery, you add the css to `#slider` and the `ul`. I'd suggest setting the height and width on `#slider` and removing it from `ul` and `li`. Check this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfbmma1r/

Comment: thank you for answer. seems I misunderstood something (

Comment: You are welcome. Did it fix your problem, or would you like further explanation?

Comment: I did not, seems your code is clear to understanding but I can understood how to bind it with that code on the site

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your issue. What did you try?

Comment: I mean I have not to big knowlages in js, so I am not sure where to put your code. if you can update it with full stack lines it will be perfect. thank you for help

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle with every removed and added code explained: http://jsfiddle.net/cm2z3h55/. In the CSS, look at `#slider`, `#slider ul` and `#slider ul li`. In the JS, check out line 11 to 28.

Comment: I will up vote your answer because it solve the issue with width, but here is another issue right when we change width (increase it), i see another div, but it will be perfect if I can see just one div, with different width. but thank you! in any case question answered.